# Number of ways to sum [1..n] with [n+1..2n] such that each sum is prime

Tags: code-golf, combinatorics, primes, sequence, permutations

Let \$n > 0\$. Let \$X = 1, 2,...,n\$ and \$Y = n+1, n+2, ..., 2n\$. Define \$a(n)\$ as the number of permutations \$p\$ of \$Y\$ such that every element of \$X + p(Y)\$ is prime. For example:

```
n = 2
X = [1,2]
Y = [3,4]
p_0(Y) = [3,4] => X + p0(Y) = [4,6] => No
p_1(Y) = [4,3] => X + p1(Y) = [5,5] => Yes
a(2) = 1
```

In as few bytes as possible, write a program or function which produces this sequence ([A070897](https://oeis.org/A070897)), either as an infinite list on STDOUT, or in your interpreter of choice.

The output should start at \$n=1\$, and each entry should be on a newline and undecorated, i.e.:

```
1
1
1
1
2
...
```

### Examples

\$a(1)=1\$ because each list `[1]`, `[2]` has only 1 element

\$a(5)=2\$ because there are two permutations: `[(1,10),(2,9),(3,8),(4,7),(5,6)]` and `[(1,6),(2,9),(3,10),(4,7),(5,8)]`

### Rules

No built-in primality tests. No lookup table ;). No standard loopholes.

Comment: So we have to output an infinite list ? All programs will be non-terminating then and for most of them, you won't be even able to see the output as the output will be provided on program termination only.

Comment: I'd suggest first `N` elements of the list...

Comment: I like non-terminating in this case, it's a little different to normal.

Comment: Do we have to print the results as we calculate them ? Or we are good if we can print them in one shot at the end of the program .. (which is most probably due to crashing by out of memory error)

Comment: They should be printed as they are calculated.

Comment: Is using built in prime factorization methods allowed ? (I thought they are automatically disallowed when you say no built in prime tests)

Comment: I'd say a prime factorisation method is a prime test...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## Pyth - <strike>35</strike> <strike>32</strike> 27 bytes

The obvious approach. <strike>The while loop logic is taking a lot of bytes.</strike> Thanks to @Jakube for telling me about `.V` and saving a lot of bytes. Explanation coming soon.

```
.V1lf!sm%h.!J++hbd@TdhJb.pb
```

[Try first n here online](http://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=K1WgQKlf!sm%25h.!tddm%2Bhk%40TklT.prhKhyK%3DhK&input=6&debug=0)

Comment: @Optimizer if you run it locally. Instant and infinite output are both obviously impossible online.

Comment: @Optimizer nope, its a built-in *prime factorization* function. :)

Comment: @Optimizer ok, i'll change it.

Comment: @Jakube shoot, Pyth has an infinite map, did not realize that. I'm feeling pretty stupid now.

Comment: @Jakube the `.V` really helped, but yours seems not to be working. You seem to be doing permutations on a urange instead of `n+1...2n`.

Comment: @Jakube oh, sorry.

Answer (score 4):

## CJam, <s>38 35</s> 32 bytes

```
0{)_e!{ee{1b1$+)_m!)\)%},!},,p}h
```

This is an infinite list version. If you run it using the [Java compiler](https://sourceforge.net/projects/cjam/), you will keep on getting result for increasing `n` on each line until the program crashes (if it does. Did not test).

For sanity, run the finite version [using this link](http://cjam.aditsu.net/#code=ri%7B)%3AXe!%7Bee%7B1bX%2B)_m!)%5C)%25%7D%2C!%7D%2C%2Cp%7D%2F&input=6). You can change the number in the input to see a longer list.

**How it works**:

```
0{                            }h  e# This acts as an infinite do-while loop here
  )_                              e# Starting from 0, increment the number and copy it
                                  e# Lets call this number at each iteration as N
    e!                            e# Get all possible permutations of the array 0..N-1
      {                   },      e# Filter the list of permutations based on this code block
       ee                         e# Convert the permutation array into an [index value]
                                  e# pair array. For ex. [5 2]ee gives [[0 5] [1 2]]
         {             },         e# Pass each index value pair through this filter
          1b1$+)                  e# Sum the index and value and add current N + 1 to it
                                  e# At this point, we have something equivalent to
                                  e# pairwise addition of [1 .. n] and [n .. 2n - 1]
                _m!)\)%           e# Now we do ((N - 1)! + 1)%N to see if N is prime
                                  e# This is Wilson's theorem and will give 0 for primes
                         !        e# Now we have a filtered index-value pairs which all
                                  e# correspond to non-prime numbers. If the list is empty,
                                  e# Then all numbers are prime. Thus we do a ! on empty list
                                  e# to get truthy.
                            ,p    e# Take the total permutations where X + pN(Y) are all
                                  e# primes and print the number to STDOUT immediately
                                  e# We are left with the initial incremented N on stack
                                  e# which is always non-zero, so the loop continues
                                  e# infinitely
```

*UPDATE: 2 bytes saved, thanks to Martin!*

Comment: Upvote for sanity. I think that time will end before you get an integer overflow though ;)

Answer (score 3):

## Python 2, 147 bytes

```py
from itertools import*
n=1;R=range
while n:print sum(all(x%d for x in map(sum,zip(R(n),c))for d in R(2,x))for c in permutations(R(n+2,2*n+2)));n+=1
```

The `import itertools` rule of thumb tells me there's probably a better way...

A few bytes are saved by summing `[0 ... n-1]` with `[n+2 ... 2n+1]` instead.

Answer (score 1):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 20 bytes

```
+RŒ!+€RÆḍỊP€SṄ¬
1Ç1#
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8/1876OgkRe1HTWuCDrc93NH7cHdXAJAT/HBny6E1XIaH2w2V//8HAA)

This gets exponentially slower for each new \$n\$ it calculates, so times out on TIO after having printed \$a(9) = 40\$. Given enough time/memory however, it will eventually print all the elements in the sequence.

### How it works

```
1Ç1# - Main link. No arguments
1    - Starting from n = 1...
   # - ...count up n = 1, 2, ...
  1  - ...until 1 n returns true when...
 Ç   - ...run over the helper link.
       As the helper link ends with ¬ (logical NOT), no n will return true

+RŒ!+€RÆḍỊP€SṄ¬ - Helper link. Takes n on the left
 R              - [1, 2, ..., n]
+               - [n+1, n+2, ..., 2n]
  Œ!            - All permutations
      R         - [1, 2, ..., n]
     €          - For each perumation:
    +           -   Add [1, 2, ..., n] elementwise
       Æḍ       - Proper divisor counts
         Ị      - Equal to 1?
           €    - For each:
          P     -   All true?
            S   - Count the true permutations
             Ṅ  - Print
              ¬ - Logical NOT to continue the infinite loop
```